# blacklisting/validating/generating JWT Refresh Tokens

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi

I issue an access token along with a refresh token upon successful login. They are both saved in same site cookies in the browser. A custom middleware will put the token in `Authorization` header before the authentication process. This middleware will also check if the access token is expired, if it is it will try the refresh token, if validated it will save two new cookies(the new refresh token and new access token) and pass the new generated access token with the current request.
Is this how we are supposed to implement refresh tokens? If I want to blacklist a specific refresh token, should i save all refresh tokens in the database?

```
 string auth = httpContext.Request.Cookies["AuthToken"];
 if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(auth))
 {
   httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"AuthorizationCookieNotFound");
   return _next(httpContext); //That token wont be accepted i just
   // put it there for the sake of demonstration



 }
 httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {auth}");
 return _next(httpContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be very careful while storing refresh tokens and they must be kept at some secret place otherwise you know the consequences.

I assume you are using "Aurhorization Code flow" here. So it's a good idea to store the refresh tokens in the db against the username and you can add an extra column e.g "IsRevoked" for status purpose and then you can blacklist/whitelist the tokens basked on the username and isrevoked status.

See [this](https://dev.to/cotter/localstorage-vs-cookies-all-you-need-to-know-about-storing-jwt-tokens-securely-in-the-front-end-15id) link about storing tokens.